# ifelse statement in python similar to R

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any `ifelse`  statement in python similar to R? I have a pandas.core.series.Series `ds` of length 64843. I need to take log of each data point of this series. Some of the value in series are 0. In R I could write

```
ifelse(ds==0,0,log(z))
```

But in python I'm not seeing similar type of statement. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: In python there's elif statement which I think is the equivalent is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) generally, but for `log` is possible add parameter `where` to [`numpy.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html).

This functions return numpy 1d array, so for new `Series` is necessary contructor:

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,5])

s1 = pd.Series(np.log(s,where=s>0), index=s.index)
```

Or:

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.where(s==0,0,np.log(s)), index=s.index)
print (s1)
0    0.000000
1    0.000000
2    1.609438
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case it is easier to just fill in the `0`'s first and then call `log`:

```
ds[ds == 0] = 1
ds = np.log(ds)
```

Be careful when you have values in your Series between 0 and 1, those will map to `-Inf` and 0, so your scale will not be continuous anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
ds[0 if ds == 0 else math.log(ds)]
```

Comment: From review: could you please add more detail to your answer?